# How to fix preflight cors error in next.js and express?

Tags: typescript, firebase, express, next.js

I have a client component for log in, in my next app.
What I'm doing is sending the user-id to my firebase cloud function to create a session cookie, and then respond with that cookie via `res.cookie`

```
 const loginUser = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const idToken = await user.getIdToken();
      // create session cookie from the idToken
      const res = await fetch(
        "http://123.0.0.1:4001/myApp/us-central1/api/login",
        {
          method: "POST",
          credentials: "include",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
          },
          cache: "no-store",
        }
      );

      console.log("res: ", res);
    } catch (error) {
      const err = error as Error;
      console.log("res-err: ", err);
    }
};
```

but I'm getting preflight cors error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://123.0.0.1:4001/myApp/us-central1/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

I tried everything on my express firebase cloud function, but still getting cors error and preflight status code 204

```
    app.use(
      cors({
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        credentials: true,
      })
    );
    
    app.options('*', (req, res) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
      res.send();
    });
    
    ... my login routes
   export const api = onRequest({ cors: true }, app); // so that I can use regular express code
```

I'm new to next js, is there something I need to setup correctly there?